# How Angular CLI generate and refer JS files for each components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular. I'm using the Angular CLI to create project and components. I know how to create a project and run it using CLI. I'm still trying to understand the basics of Angular. 
Can someone help me to understand followings,

1) Components are different files. Does Webpack generate a single file by bundling all ts files? If so how Module import mechanism work? We import modules using file path.

2) How does these generated js file/files refer in html file? When I open the index.html file I only see references to inline.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js and main.bundle.js. What are these files?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Here is what I have learned so far.

- Angular CLI config file is .angular-cli.json
- Angular use tsc (Typescript Compiler) to transpile the EC6 to EC5. the config file is tsconfig.json
- Angular use Webpack to bundle the js and css files to combine and deliver to browser. By default, Angular CLI manages the underlying webpack configuration. The webpack.config.js is the config file. The file could be exported using "ng eject" command.
- Angular use CommonJS as module target when compiling the code. CommonJS + Webpack convert Typescript's Native EC6 modules to single file (main.boundle.js) module system that supports the browser.

@LorenzoImperatrice has answered my second question. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, **AngularCLI** (that use Webpack) generate a single file with all of your code from every component in it, you can see this file by running `ng build`, this will create a directory in your root folder named "dist", at this point just search for main.bundle.js and you can see the generated code. The compiler options of the app are in the file "tsconfig.app.json" and "tsconfig.json". Most of the time you don't want to modify those files at all.

2) As I said in the point 1, is generated a unique file with everything inside (main.boundle.js).

- **inline.bundle.js**: It's the Webpack loader ad it's used to bootstrap Webpack and to load other files
- **polyfills.bundle.js**: It is used for support different browsers and is created based on the file "polyfills.ts".
- **styles.bundle.js**: It is used to injecting the general style that you need inside your application, is possible to customize what inject from the file ".angular-cli.json"
- **vendor.bundle.js**: Same of "styles.bundle.js" but with the js script

Comment: You are missing: main.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js and depending on the application, bundles generated for lazy modules.

Comment: "As I said in the point 1, is generated a unique file with everything inside (main.boundle.js)." with this I mean that main.boundle.js is the file that contains all of your components, services... now I'm going to edit for inline.boundle.js

Comment: @Jota.Toledo edited with inline, and i didn't undertand what you mean with the second part of your comment: "depending on the application, bundles generated for lazy modules"

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Something wort mentioning is that, at least in my local, it seems that the bundled files generated by serve/build differ (at least in the 1.6.x version). If an application has lazy modules, the main.bundle wont contain the complete application. Instead, it will be a part of it that works as entry point so to say.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the versions before Angular 2, but a lot is changed now. Never hear about this problem sorry.

Comment: If main.bundle.js file contains all the code of app, How does the Model Import mechanism work? The file path is used to import a module. Can you guys point me some tutories that explain how Angular CLI + Webpack works under the hood?

Comment: I’m sorry, maybe I don’t get what the question is. Yes main.bundle.js contains all the code that you had written. But after that there is not a lot to understand, Webpack just import what you write, and compile it as standard JS code, that’s all. It is going to get every piece of thing that you import to the main module recursivly until it get all the classes that you used inside the project.